# create tuples from lines given in .txt file via Python

Tags: python, list, python-re

Here are lines from the file `listing.txt` which contains a list of several files with one line per file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jttoivon hyad-all    2356 Dec 11 11:50 add_colab_link.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164519 Dec 28 17:59 basics.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164477 Nov  5 19:21 basics.ipynb.orig
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  115587 Dec 11 11:50 bayes.ipynb
drwxr-xr-x 4 jttoivon hyad-all    4096 Nov 29 13:07 _build
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  198820 Dec 11 11:50 clustering.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    6647 Dec 11 12:20 conf.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   41828 Nov 28 13:26 example_figure2.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  125079 Nov 28 13:26 example_figure2.xcf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   24139 Nov 28 12:03 example_figure.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jttoivon hyad-all     650 Nov 28 12:03 example_figure.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   43632 Nov  2 22:05 exception_hierarchy.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   24366 Nov  2 21:26 exception_hierarchy.svg
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   72095 Oct  3 17:36 extra.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all 1207075 Nov 28 16:02 face.png
-rwxr--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all     897 Nov 12 10:59 generate_contents.py
drwx------ 8 jttoivon hyad-all    4096 Dec 27 13:55 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all      19 Dec 10 10:24 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  890349 Dec 11 11:50 image_processing.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all     689 Dec 10 10:28 index.rst
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    5254 Nov  3 18:46 inheritance_hierarchy.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    7271 Nov  3 18:46 inheritance_hierarchy.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    4091 Dec 11 11:50 instructions.ipynb
drwx------ 2 jttoivon hyad-all    4096 Nov 30 14:13 .ipynb_checkpoints
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   54011 Dec 11 11:50 linear_regression.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all     620 Nov  1 11:44 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   52191 Dec 11 11:50 matplotlib.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    1920 Nov 30 11:37 notes.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   82564 Dec 11 11:50 numpy.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   10201 Nov  3 16:36 package.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    5742 Nov  3 16:37 package.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  913641 Nov 26 10:58 painting.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  348531 Dec 28 13:40 pandas.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  100697 Dec 11 11:50 pca.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   32451 Oct  5 19:21 Python-basic-elements.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all      82 Nov 13 12:55 requirements.txt
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all      81 Nov 13 12:44 requirements.txt.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    2836 Nov 12 10:58 sisallys.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  128194 Nov 23 12:58 testing.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all     691 Nov 29 16:27 .travis.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all     973 Oct 31 14:01 typing1.fig
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    3747 Oct 31 14:01 typing1.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    1093 Oct 31 14:01 typing2.fig
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    4053 Oct 31 14:02 typing2.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   12220 Oct 31 14:07 typing.svg
-rwx------ 1 jttoivon hyad-all     766 Oct 25 12:10 versions.py
```

Each line contains certain fields: access rights, number of references, owner’s name, name of owning group, file size, date, filename. These fields are separated with a help of one or more spaces; there may be spaces also within these seven fields.

I was asked to write function `file_listing` that loads the given file and should return a list of tuples (size, month, day, hour, minute, filename) by using some regular expressions; I chose `findall` method.

I wrote the following code:

```
import re

def file_listing(filename="src/listing.txt"):
    with open("src/listing.txt", mode='r') as f:
        for line in f:
            #print(line)
            d = re.findall('^(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+', line)
            #print(d)
            for idx, item in enumerate(d):
                print(item[4:])
    return d
```

I don't know how to implement a proper search to get a result `(25399, "Nov", 2, 21, 25, "exception_hierarchy.pdf")` for a line `-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all 25399 Nov 2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf` from the file. So far, it looks as follows: `('25399', 'Nov', '2', '21:25', 'exception_hierarchy.pdf')`. Any ideas how to solve the challenge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So all that's left is splitting `'21:25'` into `21` and `25`. Have you tried using the `str.split` method?

Comment: @mkrieger1: Not only this (but this also). When tested, I got the following errors: 
Failed: test.test_file_listing.FileListing.test_content
        '-rwx------' is not an instance of <class 'int'> : size has wrong type!

Failed: test.test_file_listing.FileListing.test_names
        False is not true

Comment: @mkrieger1: Well, I just tried to find a way to get rid of first four items from each tuple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions here. The case is clear, every line comes in a well defined format. So why not simply use string's `split()` method:

```
def result(line):
    tmp = line.split()
    return (
        int(tmp[4]),
        tmp[5],
        int(tmp[6]),
        int(tmp[7].split(":")[0]),
        int(tmp[7].split(":")[1]),
        tmp[8]
    )

line = '-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all 25399 Nov 2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf'

print(result(line))
# (25399, 'Nov', 2, 21, 25, 'exception_hierarchy.pdf')
```

---

A more proper way could be to unpack the result of `split()` into named variables, e.g:

```
def result(line):
    permissions, hardlinks, owner_user, owner_group, filesize, month, day, time, filename = line.split()
    return (
        int(filesize),
        month,
        int(day),
        int(time.split(":")[0]),
        int(time.split(":")[1]),
        filename
    )
```